# Update SQLite database after updating app, even if user doesn't open the app

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is there a way to update a SQLite database, or rather run a bunch of code, after updating an app even though the user refrain from opening the app?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: In my case, updating the database is a matter of extracting a gzip file from the assets folder. So, I need to start an AsyncTask after updating the app **even though the user doesn't open the app**.

I've tried initiating the code from the `onCreate()` method of the Application class, but, of course that didn't work. Application classes initiate when the app is run, right?

Comment: No, you have to have the application started to run any code. Otherwise malicious apps could just do whatever they wanted. Your only other option is to create a listener that starts your app on boot, but please don't do that.

Comment: Why to do you say not to create a listener that starts the app on boot?

Comment: Because if everyone has their app do that then it takes a long time for the device to fully boot. Don't do it unless your users expect your app to be running at boot.